# How to visit html static site inside web2py project

Tags: python, web, web2py

Say I have some comp `html` files designer gave me and I want to just use it right away in a web2py website running on `127.0.0.1`, with web2py MVC structure, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web2py serves static files from the application's `/static` folder, so just put the files in there. If you need to generate links to them, you can use the `URL` helper: `URL('static', 'path/to/static_file.html')` (where the second argument represents the path *within* the `/static` folder).